# Debugging Camel in IntelliJ community edition

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-camel, ide, jetbrains-ide, intellij-plugin

I am using Apache Camel with IntelliJ Community Edition.

I've [seen on the official site](https://camel.apache.org/blog/2021/12/camelDebuggerForIntelliJ/) some kind of debugger for XML DSL, but is not very clear how to use it...

Does it works for the Community edition also? It asks to create a *Camel SpringBoot Application run configuration*, how I do it?

In fact, when I check for this application, I can't find nothing. I have installed the recommended plugin.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Camel plugin is not compatible with IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1. Try using 2021.3 instead.

Comment: As today this is not valid anymore: updated plugin works well with 2022.1

Comment: In my case, using IntelliJ 2022.2 the plugin caused the debugger not working anymore. In essence, pressing the debug button did literally nothing anymore and there weren't even errors in the idea.log. Only disabling camel debugger in the plugin settings allowed me to use the IDEA's debugger again

Comment: True for me as well (2022.2 Ultimate Edition). Debug buttons - no matter where they are - do nothing until I disable the Camel plugin.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure the plugin is installed and enabled. Check your Preferences -> Plugins -> Installed and make sure the Apache Camel plugin is installed, enabled and its version is 0.8.5.

As previously suggested, if you are running version later than 2021.3.2, the plugin may not be supported, try downgrading to 2021.3.2.

Also, check Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Apache Camel -> Miscellaneous and make sure the checkbox "Enable Camel Debugger" is selected.